# Create an attribute without encapsulation

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

Simple question about oop.

Let's pretend I have a class with an attribute in it.

```
public class Person {
  // Attributes
  private int age; 
}
```

If I remove the encapsulation of my attribute *age*, will it still be *private*? or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the [tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).  It should explain.

Comment: If your field doesn't have a modifier, it will be package-private.

Comment: Let's pretend that it is package private !!!

Comment: If you don't declare explicitly the visibility of a Java attribute, it will remain in some kind of "semi-protected" status; the attribute will be visible in the class itself and in the package, but won't be visible in subclasses or in the rest of the project. This is identified as a non-good software design practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it, the attribute will be accessible from the class and from the package as well, but it won't be accessible from subclasses and the rest of the project. Therefore, the attribute will be some kind of `semi protected` variable.  It is not a recommended approach in OOP.

You might find this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) helpful.

Hope it helps.

Clemencio Morales Lucas.

Comment: The last sentence really boggles me. I find default visibility as a very useful aspect of encapsulation. Please prove this statement or remove it.

Comment: If you had read the link I post on the answer (which belongs to the Oracle Official Java SE Tutorials), you would read that "Use private unless you have a good reason not to.". This means that, in almost all cases, you have to use private visibility.

Comment: I did read the linked document. However, there is no indication of 'default visibility is not a recommended approach in OOP'. Instead, your cited bullet point begins with "Use the most restrictive access level that makes sense for a particular member". That's the recommended approach.

Comment: I insist, the indication is "Use private unless you have a good reason not to." By using private, you are using the most restrictive access level. If that makes sense (and experience tell me that it makes sense in most cases), private is the visibility you need, so that's the recommended approach. In your words, "Use the most restrictive access level that makes sense for a particular member". Private is more restrictive than Default visibility, so you implicitly said I am right.